# SharePoint 2010 Crawler: The crawler only crawl the default page

Tags: 2010, 2007, site, crawl

I am using SP 2010 crawler to crawl SP Site. But it seems that the crawler only crawl the dafault page (The page that mark as default), the other pages are not crawled even if I already published all of these pages. And All of these pages can access by the crawl user.

I did some research on this issue and found this article --> "http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZW/sharepoint2010setup/thread/3ad9e92f-0ccd-41b8-ad1e-d1072a985442"

They suggest to reset the index. But now I'm working on the production environment. So, this solution will have an affect on our user.

So, does anyone have any suggestion?

Best Regards,

Bo

Answer (score 1):

I resolve my issue by remove some exclude rules.. such as 
$HOSTNAME/.*AllItems.*,
$HOSTNAME/.*/Forms/*.*,
$HOSTNAME/.*Library.*,
$HOSTNAME/Documents/*.*,
$HOSTNAME/.*Disform.*

I don't know why but it works :)

Bo

Comment: Please mark this as the accpeted answer, since it may hel other users with the same issue. Thank you!